# MIN Function not ignoring FALSE

Tags: excel

I have a formula inside a MIN function that evaluates to FALSE. MIN should ignore logical values, but it evaluates to 0 if the value is evaluated inside the MIN function:

```
=MIN(FALSE,2) >>> 0
```

But

```
A1=FALSE

=MIN(A1,2) >>> 2
```

Is this a bug in Excel? I'm using new latest version (190811) on a mac.

Comment: See https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-min-function. "The MIN function ignores TRUE and FALSE values, and numbers entered as text, unless they are typed directly into the list of arguments." If an argument is or evaluates to TRUE or FALSE, it is not ignored.

Comment: There are workarounds that you could look implement most likely - depends on the context. An initial thought is to modify your equations that lead to the Boolean responses to use `1 or 0` instead of `TRUE or FALSE`. An easy way to do that is to next whatever equation you have inside `INT( Boolean Test )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug but by design:

From the [`MIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152) documentation:

> Logical values and text representations of numbers that you type directly into the list of arguments are counted.

Or from [this link](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-min-function):

> The MIN function ignores TRUE and FALSE values, and numbers entered as text, unless they are typed directly into the list of arguments.

In other words, if an argument is or evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, it is not ignored.

There is most likely an alternative, but you would need to share more detail - what is the function that resolves to `TRUE/FALSE` - to propose an adequate solution.

Comment: I have several VLOOKUP functions inside a MIN function. If one cell that holds the     lookup_value is blank (they are all optional) VLOOKUP and then MIN evaluates to #N/A. I wanted to catch that error by passing FALSE to the MIN function. I could pass a very high number instead like 1E+99, but thats a hack.